# Is it $x=1, y=2, z=3$ the unique solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Find $x,y, z\in \mathbb{N}^{*}$ s.t. $$x^3+y^3+z^3=(xyz)^2.$$

$x=1, y=2, z=3$  is a solution and all the others permutations.

Is this the unique solution? How can I prove that is unique?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is unique.

Assume that $x\leqslant y\leqslant z$. Then $(xyz)^2\leqslant3z^3$, and therefore$$x^2y^2\leqslant3z.\tag1$$And, since $z^2\mid x^3+y^3+z^3$, you know that $z^2\mid x^3+y^3$ and that therefore$$x^3+y^3\geqslant z^2.\tag2$$It follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that$$18y^3\geqslant9(x^3+y^3)\geqslant9z^2=(3z)^2\geqslant(xy)^4.$$So, $x^4y\leqslant18$, and therefore $x\leqslant1$ and $y\leqslant18$. From $(2)$, you can deduce now that $z^2\leqslant1+18^3$, and so $z\leqslant76$. And now, a brute force search shows that your solution is indeed the only solution.